# Double precision floating-point comparison

Tags: c++, comparison, floating-point, double, leveldb

I'm a little confused here- would comparison of doubles still work correctly when they're stored as opaque (binary) fields? The problem I'm facing is the fact that the double includes a leading bit for the sign (i.e. positive or negative) and when they're stored as binary data I'm not sure it will be compared correctly:

[image]

I want to ensure that the comparison will work correctly, because I'm using a double as a part of a [key tuple (e.g. ) in LevelDB](http://leveldb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/index.html) and I want to preserve the data locality for positive and negative numbers. LevelDB only uses opaque fields as keys, but it does allow the user to specify his/her own comparator.  However, I just want to make sure that I don't specify a comparator unless I absolutely need to:

```
// Three-way comparison function:
//   if a < b: negative result
//   if a > b: positive result
//   else: zero result
inline int Compare(const unsigned char* a, const unsigned char* b) const 
{
    if (*(double*)a < *(double*)b) return -1;
    if (*(double*)a > *(double*)b) return +1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two things: This will fail if both parameters turn out to be `NAN` since `NAN != NAN`. The other thing is to watch out for alignment. Not all systems support misaligned access.

Comment: @Mysticial, thanks for the feedback... I'll try to figure out what to do with `NAN`. So my assumption is correct? I have to specify a comparison operator for keys that contain doubles?

Comment: Well, I'm not at all familiar with leveldb. So I didn't understand half the question - hence why I didn't post it as an answer. But yes, if you need it to return true if they are the same in binary, then you'll have to add trap cases for NAN. Also, comparing `NAN`s is not transitive, so you'll have to handle that as well.

Comment: Why are you using `const unsigned char *` instead of `const void *`?

Comment: As long as the double values are being compared *as doubles*, the representation (sign bit, etc.) is irrelevant.  NaNs are an issue.  Alignment could be as well, but if `a` and `b` are initialized as converted pointers to properly-aligned `double` objects.

Comment: @ChrisLutz I don't know if it would make a difference either way, but my example was simplified from `virtual int Compare(const Slice& a, const Slice& b)` and you look at the `Slice`'s data in order to compare two `Slice`s... the data is of type `const char*` so I guess to be more accurate I should remove the `unsigned` keyword.

Comment: @Link - I missed the C++ tag and your code didn't look very C++ as written, so I assumed this was supposed to be a comparison function to pass to `qsort` or something similar.

Comment: @ChrisLutz no problem... the comparison function is passed in Google's LevelDB which uses it to sort the records by key. It's important for me to have a good comparison function (both fast and correct) since I will have millions of records and this function may be called a 100k-200k times a second (which it probably will be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making my comments an answer.

There are two things that could go wrong:

1. If either (or both) parameters is `NAN`, comparisons will always return false. So even if the binary representation is the same, `NAN == NAN` will always be false. Furthermore, it violates comparison transitivity.
2. If either parameter isn't properly aligned (since they are char pointers), you could run into problems on machines that don't support misaligned memory access. And for those that do, you may encounter a performance hit.

So to get around this problem, you'll need to add a trap case that will be invoked if either parameter turns out to be `NAN`. (I'm not sure on the status of `INF`.)

Because of the need for this trap case, you will need to define your own comparison operator.

Comment: @Mystical: Could you please elaborate on point 2. Specifically which machines, and how big a performance hit is to be expected?

Comment: When accessing multi-byte words from memory (such as an 8-byte double), the address should be divisible by the size of the word. When you use pointers normally, this is ensured by the compiler. However, when you start doing pointer-casts, the alignment for one type (`char`) might be insufficient for another type (`double`). On a machine that does not support misaligned access, the hardware will throw an exception. (crash) On a machine that does support it, there is usually a penalty because the hardware need to do two separate accesses, then combine them and extract the relevant portion.

Comment: Continuing since I exceeded 500 characters: x86/x64 will allow misaligned memory accesses for everything except for the SIMD vector load/stores. For those, there is a separate misaligned load/store instruction. On many RISC architectures (such as ARM, Itanium, etc...), alignment is required. In the case of x86/x64, the performance hit of a misaligned access is highly dependent on the architecture - and can be anywhere from ~50 cycles for a cache-line split (on Core 2) to nearly free (on Sandy Bridge).

Comment: @mystical I don't have much control over how the keys/values are cast. Google's LevelDB only accepts keys/values of pointers to type `char` and if my key is originally of type `double` or a 64-bit `unsigned` integer, then I have to cast them to `char*` (which are the two types of keys I primarily use). LevelDB is just a key/value embedded database, so I'm not sure what's the impact of alignment and I'm not sure what I can do about it.

Comment: If you're `double` pointers are originally cast to `char*` and then back to `double*` in the function, then the alignment will be fine if the pointer value is still the same. Since it sounds like you're casting just to get around the syntax.

Comment: @Mysticial, You're correct, although in my head saying that I'm casting just to get around the syntax almost makes it sound like I'm doing something "wrong", but that's just how Google implemented LevelDB. So in that sense: yes, I'm just casting the key/value just to get around the syntax. Now I have to take care of the `NAN`s.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, I'd say that, if this going to run on x86/x64, you probably better off just ignoring the alignment issue. Whatever steps you to realign the data will probably be more expensive than just letting the hardware handle the misalignment. Furthermore, there's no overhead added for the cases where it is aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to specify your own comparison function. This is because doubles are not necessarily stored as 'big-endian' values. The exponent will not reside in memory before the mantissa even though logically it appears before the mantissa when the value is written out in big-endian format.

Of course, if you're sharing stuff between different CPU architectures in the same database, you may end up with weird endian problems anyway just because you stored stuff as binary blobs.

Lastly, even if you could control for endianness I would still not trust it.  For example, if a double is not normalized it may not compare correctly to another double when compared as binary data.

Of course, everything the other person said about alignment and odd values like NAN and INF are important to pay attention to when writing a comparison function. But, as far as whether you should write one at all, I would have to say that it would be a really good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your number format conforms to the IEEE 754 standard. If that's the case, then a simple signed-integer comparison won't work -- if both numbers are negative, the result of the comparison is reversed. So you do have to provide your own comparator.